# Images in Master Page not displaying after restore

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, master-page, backup, restore

I made a backup of my site using:

```
backup-spsite -force
```

Then on another server I created a new web application, then inside it I created a new site collection and then restore the above backup using command:

```
restore-spsite -force
```

Now when I open my site on new server, the images (and may be javascript file too) defined in my master page are not loading. Why is that? Do I need to do something to make them visible?
All other images which are in my page layout are loading but not master page.

Comment: Looks like I found the problem. I noticed that some files are checked out from previous machine from where I moved the backup hence they were not properly loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that some files are checked out from previous machine from where I moved the backup hence they were not properly loading.